# How can I animate a series of images in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI and iOS development (I started learning 2 days ago). Before this I was doing Android apps. I learned some of the basics but I can't figure it out how can I animate several images. I need to display a series of images with 1.2 seconds delay before changing them in a frame.

I found some code here, but they use UIImage which is the old framework and the animation can't be stopped.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SplashScreen: UIViewRepresentable {
 let imageSize: CGSize
 let imageNames: [String]
 let duration: Double

 func makeUIView(context: Self.Context) -> UIView {
    let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0
        , width: imageSize.width, height: imageSize.height))

    let animationImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageSize.width, height: imageSize.height))

    animationImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    animationImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    animationImageView.autoresizesSubviews = true
    animationImageView.animationRepeatCount = 3
    animationImageView.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill

    var images = [UIImage]()
    imageNames.forEach { imageName in
        if let img = UIImage(named: imageName) {
            images.append(img)
        }
    }

    animationImageView.image = UIImage.animatedImage(with: images, duration: duration)
    animationImageView.image = animationImageView.animationImages?.last!

    containerView.addSubview(animationImageView)

    return containerView
}

 func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SplashScreen>) {

 }
}
```

This code is from Julio Bailon.

I couldn't find any tutorial which shows how to do this in SwiftUI.

**1. Animate the images like 3 times.

2. On end, launch another ViewController without the possibility of going back. (I am thinking like activities on Android but I don't know how much that helps)**

Comment: show your own try and refer this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and then someone probably could help you

Comment: Done ! I added some code